# When I try to run this I get this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python

```
HomeworkList = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
WeekDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
PersonNames = ["Jack", "Mary", "John"]

for people in range(len(PersonNames)):
    for day in range(len(WeekDays)):
        HomeworkList[PersonNames][WeekDays] = int(input("Total minutes for %s, on %s \n>" % (PersonNames[people], WeekDays[day])))

HomeworkList[PersonNames][WeekDays] = int(input("Total minutes for %s, on %s \n>" % (PersonNames[people],WeekDays[day])))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

whenever I try to run this code I get this error, for example I input the number 30 and it errors out, I am new to Python may someone help

Comment: Please share the entire error message. What do/don’t you understand from the error?

Comment: `HomeworkList[PersonNames][WeekDays]` Those are lists and can't be indexes. Did you mean `HomeworkList[people][day]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slice by an integer value, currently you are putting the entire list of `PersonNames` and `WeekDays` in your slice. `people` and `day` are type `int`.

Your loop should be:

```
for people in range(len(PersonNames)):
    for day in range(len(WeekDays)):
        HomeworkList[people][day] = int(input("Total minutes for %s, on %s \n>" % (PersonNames[people], WeekDays[day])))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message states, you pass a list instead of an int to a list.

e.g. in this line:

```
HomeworkList[PersonNames][WeekDays]
type(PersNames) == list
type(WeekDays) == list
```

You probably want instead is use this

```
HomeworkList[people][day]
type(people) == int
type(day) == int
```

To make the difference more clear this is what each statement looks like when you replace the variable with its values:

```
HomeworkList[["Jack", "Mary", "John"]][["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]]
```

vs. e.g.

```
HomeworkList[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

indexing 'HomeworkList' should be like this below

specifying integers..
HomeworkList[2][3]

or using slices..
HomeworkList[2:3]